I want to create a group on Zoho Cliq, assign member to the group and able to fetch the chat
I want to create a group on Zoho Cliq, assign member to the group and able to fetch the chat.
I'm getting error invalid url
I've tried this=
Request method: POST
API endpoint.: https://cliq.zoho.com/api/v2/groups
Payload:
 $groupData = array(
            "group_name" => "Testing Group name",
            "description" => "Testing Group description",
            "members" => array("testuser@example.com")
        );

but it's giving the below error
Array
(
[code] => request_url_invalid
[message] => The request URL is invalid. Please check the URL pattern.
)

I'm working on Yii2 PHP. CURL related setup, access_token, this setup is already there.

Can you please point us to the documentation for this endpoint, that you are basing this on?

I've not found any info about the group, but it has departments https://www.zoho.com/cliq/help/restapi/v2/#Departments and teams https://www.zoho.com/cliq/help/restapi/v2/#Teams, where you can manage the members
